# Pip install error

Tags: python, pip, codec, easy-install

Whenever I try to use `pip` I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 720, in <module>
    class Environment(object):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 723, in Environment
    def __init__(self, search_path=None, platform=get_supported_platform(), python=PY_MAJOR):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 109, in get_supported_platform
    plat = 'macosx-%s-%s' % ('.'.join(_macosx_vers()[:2]), m.group(3))
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 221, in _macosx_vers
    version = platform.mac_ver()[0]
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/platform.py", line 804, in mac_ver
    info = _mac_ver_xml()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/platform.py", line 781, in _mac_ver_xml
    pl = plistlib.readPlist(fn)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plistlib.py", line 78, in readPlist
    rootObject = p.parse(pathOrFile)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plistlib.py", line 406, in parse
    parser.ParseFile(fileobj)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plistlib.py", line 418, in handleEndElement
    handler()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plistlib.py", line 452, in end_key
    self.currentKey = self.getData()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plistlib.py", line 436, in getData
    data = data.encode("ascii")
LookupError: no codec search functions registered: can't find encoding
```

trying to run `sudo easy_install pip` results in the same message. I have previously used `pip` and received this when trying to install a `virtualenv` for a project. I can't think of any recent updates or system changes that would have caused this. Has anyone encountered this error message before?

Comment: As I can this this is a OS X M-Lion. Is this native installation?

Comment: What do you get `'test'.encode("ascii")`?

Comment: I suggest you to follow step by step the following tutorial to install everything properly on mac lion (or lion mountain).: http://www.thisisthegreenroom.com/2011/installing-python-numpy-scipy-matplotlib-and-ipython-on-lion/